# Using two cores of esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I know that the esp8266 is a dual core micro controler, is there a way to use control these two cores to different codes simultanuesly using arduino ide?

Answer (score 2):

[`ESP8266`](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp8266ex/overview) is based on a Tensilica L106 32-bit RISC processor [`ref`](https://ip.cadence.com/news/243/330/Tensilica-Unveils-Diamond-Standard-106Micro-Processor-Smallest-Licensable-32-bit-Core) which is **single-core** processor and thus you can't do real multiprocessing on it.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but there is a good Scheduler [library](https://github.com/bmellstrom/esp8266-arduino-threads) that may help you run simultaneous functions.

**P.S:** In general on a multi-core microcontroller, you can't simply put multiple codes inside each core. The process of multiprocessing should handle by its firmware and you need to use its tools like SDKs to do real multiprocessing.